# b-form-checkbox in list group doesn't work

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I added a check box into the list group, the list group contain 2 item, the first row of check box is work but the second one doesn't work when I click the check box, the different is item 2 contains 'href="#"'.

```
            <b-list-group>
                <b-list-group-item>
                    Cras justo odio
                    <b-form-checkbox switch />
                </b-list-group-item>
                <b-list-group-item href="#">
                    Dapibus ac facilisis in
                    <b-form-checkbox  switch />
                </b-list-group-item>
            </b-list-group>
```

May I know how to fix it?

Comment: ```<b-list-group-item href="#">``` It activate the switch as well as reload the page. Therefore, the switch will back or turn off again.. If you want to work the switch as well as make a link in your *b-list-group-item*, I suggest to use a button. e.i ``````<b-list-group-item button>```